# Sending Special characters as a message;

Tags: http, encoding, sms

I'm running Kannel which i use as an SMS gateway. But I've just realized some special symbols are not received on phone as they should;  @, ^ and $ are sent as some triangle; How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a charset problem. SMSes are usually received with GSM7 charset, and the characters you gave have different GSM7 numeric codes that, for example, ISO-8859-1. You should convert from GSM7 to your own character encoding.

The char @ may be problematic for another reason. In GSM7 it is s 0 (zero). If you leave it as it is and your programming language uses a zero-terminated strings -- all strings containing @ will look like they terminated just before this character.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38) for a table of GSM7 characters.

Comment: OK, to tell u the truth, that was not a lot of English. *smile*; Could u please re-explain how I can convert  from GSM7 to your own character encoding., which files to change, where 2 look for the info and such info? I'll appreciate it. My system is running on Perl and PHP.

Comment: HELLO @puzz, i've taken ure suggestion on checking out more on charsets an realized hat could be the problem. Now that is with another system and im asking the kannel users forum. Thanks alot for your help