# Special characters in SMS

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, sms-gateway

I would like to send email address in SMS which contains @ symbol. But after sending SMS its converting to ? symbol. What should do to send special characters like @ in SMS

I have tried sending 0x00 hexadecimal value for @ as a string but its sending as it is 0x00 and not converting it to @ symbol.

Comment: You can not send special symbols in SMS. Sorry

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708074/sending-special-characters-as-a-message

Answer (score 0):

try below PHP functions maybe helpful:

```
1) urlencode("Your Email");
2) utf8_encode("Your Email");
```

OR

```
urlencode(utf8_encode("Your Email"));
rawurlencode("Your Email");
```

Comment: Yes, it can not convert , as I tried with my own Way2SMS account :)

Comment: duplicate of maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599/reliable-sms-unicode-gsm-encoding-in-php